# Erro ao Criar conexão mysqli

Tags: php, linux, mysqli

Estou tentando criar uma conexão por MYSQLI mais esta dando erro 
**Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /home** 
Oque pode ser?isso

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "xx", "xxx", "xxx");
if (!$link) {
  echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
  echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
  echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
  exit;
}

echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;

mysqli_close($link);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Veja se a extensão está instalado, faça um phpinfo()

Comment: Coloquei uma imagem a cima com um print de um único registro contendo mysqli

Comment: Isso aí parece ser os creditos, veja no php.ini se tem alguma linha como `mysqli` se tiver um `;` remova ele e reinicie o apache

Comment: Qual sistema operaciional está usando?

Comment: linux na godaddy

Comment: É ubunto? fedora?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro acontece porque a extensão *mysqli* não está habilitada. A linha do `phpinfo()` que você deve procurar é *MysqlI Support enabled*.

As versões recentes de Linux da família Debian (como Ubuntu) possuem um comando especifico para habilitar módulos do PHP [<sup>*1</sup>](https://askubuntu.com/a/496160/258292):

```
sudo php5enmod mysqli
```

e reinicie o apache com

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```